# why $f(x)$is divergent?

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

Given the improper integral
$$f(x)=\int_0^1 x^m \sin x\, dx$$ where  $ m\in \mathbb{R}$

Is $f(x)$ is divergent at $m=-4/3?$

My try :  we have the inequality  $\sin x \leq x$

$f(x)  = \int_0^1 x^m \sin x \, dx$

so $$f(x) \le \int_{0}^1 x^{1+m}\,dx \le \frac{1}{2+m} <\infty$$

clearly we can see if $-2<m<0$ then $f(x)$ is convergent

and $m= -4/3 \in (-2,0)$

so $f(x)$ is convergent

But answer key show that $f(x)$ is divergent I don't understand why $f(x)$ is divergent.

Comment: as far as i can see, $f(x)$ is a constant. (since $x$ is both the variable of the integral and the variable of your function)

Comment: @NicholasRoberts i edited

Comment: Asking whether $f(x)$ is convergent for $m=-4/3$ doesn't make much sense. You mean to ask whether the integral is convergent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neat $ 0 $ bound, we have

$$x^m\sin(x)\sim x^{m+1} \;\;(x\to 0^+)$$

or

$$x^m\sin(x)\sim \frac{1}{x^{-m-1}}$$

but

$$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x^{-m-1}}\;converges$$
$$\;\iff -m-1<1$$
$$\iff m>-2$$

So, if $ m=\frac{-4}{3} $, the integral is Convergent.

Comment: u mean $f(x)$ is convergent ??

Comment: @Messififa Yes, because $ -4/3>-2$.

Comment: oks thanks u @hamam_Abdallah

Comment: @Messififa No, he does not mean $f(x)$ is convergent! That makes no sense. He means the integral is convergent.

Answer (score 2):

When $m=-4/3$, compare it with the second integral as follows:$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^{4/3}} \sin x dx \le \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^{4/3}}x dx = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^{1/3}} dx$$
The second integral is convergent since $1/3 < 1$.

So, your reasoning is right.

Comment: Why is the downvote?